# Implement the MATLAB 'fitdist' in Python

Tags: python, image, matlab, image-processing, kernel-density

I am working on a image processing tool, and I am having some trouble finding a good substitute for matlab's fitdist to a Python soltuion.

The matlab code works something like this:

`pdR = fitdist(Red,'Kernel','Support','positive');`

Any of you have found a good implementation for this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally SciPy is useful in your case:

```
import scipy.stats as st
# KDE
st.gaussian_kde(data)
# Fit to specified distribution (Normal distribution in this example)
st.norm.fit(data)
```

Full reference is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html